# Passing value between JSF Forms. I can't get it to work

Tags: jsf, web, jsf-2.2

I read the other posts about this subject but I still can't get it to work

This are my beans:

Bean1:

```
@ManagedBean()
@SessionScoped
public class Bean1 implements Serializable  {

    //Here are some important Properties

    public String buttonPressed() {

        return "bean2.xhtml";
    }
}

<h:form>
        <p:commandButton action="#{Bean1.buttonPressed}" value="Do Work"/>
</h:form>
```

Bean2:

```
@ManagedBean()
@SessionScoped
public class Bean2 implements Serializable  {

    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{Bean1}")
    private Bean1 b1;
    //getter/setter is here

    public String doWorkOnSubmit() {

        //Access important Properties from bean1
        b1.getFoo()
    }
}
```

Now I have two Problems

1.) How to call "doWorkOnSubmit" if the button in Bean1 is pressed? I can't use the constructor because it's SessionScoped and I don't know how to call doWorkOnSubmit un submit

2.)The managed property "b1" is sometimes null

Answer (score 0):

Since on clicking of `Do Work` button you are calling `Bean1.buttonPressed()` action method you can call `Bean2`s `doWorkOnSubmit()` by injecting `Bean2` in `Bean1`.

Here is your code altered:

```
@ManagedBean()
@SessionScoped
public class Bean1 implements Serializable  {

    //Here are some important Properties

    /*
     * Inject Bean2 here. since both beans are session scoped, 
     * there ain't gonna be any problem in injection.
     */
    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{Bean2}")
    private Bean2 b2;

    //GETTER SETTER for b2

    public String buttonPressed() {

        //Here you will be invoking injected managed beans method.
        b2.doWorkOnSubmit();

        return "bean2.xhtml";
    }
}
```

Comment: But I'm already injecting Bean1 in Bean2. How should a double reference work?